# Include message template created at facebook dashboard in Twilio to send message

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

- I have created 2 message templates directly on the Facebook Dashboard(which are approved).
- I have a Twilio WhatsApp Sender Account Already Linked to this number.
- So my question is how do I enable these templates on Twilio so that I can directly send these template messages from Twilio send message API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you can do on your own. You can try to reach out to support and ask them to re-synchronize the template with your Meta Business Manager. That might be able to solve your problem.

My recommendation for the future is to create the templates in the Twilio console:

> 1. Access the WhatsApp Message Templates page in [Console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/senders/whatsapp-templates?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fsms%2Fwhatsapp%2Ftemplates%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1) by navigating to **Messaging -> Senders -> WhatsApp Templates**.
> 2. Click the **Submit a Message Template** button. If you are not creating a template for the first time, you will see the **New message template** button. Click it to create additional templates.
> 3. Fill out the various fields of the template form, click **Submit Message Template** and the template will be sent to WhatsApp for approval. All templates must be approved by WhatsApp before you can use them for messaging users.